# How to manage different data types in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm new to Clickhouse and for the moment everything goes well. But I'm facing right now with a problem. I have to create data from a python script. But the values have different types. For the moment I wrote them in a string type and wrote in the other column their types.

I also tried to create tables for the different types but clickhouse doesn't manage the foreign key. And I don't know how to get the values thanks to the key.

For example I have this table :
`CREATE TABLE table(key UInt32, name String, value String, type String) ENGINE=MergeTree ORDER BY key`

I can have UInt8,..,64, Int.., Array types for my "value". But I can't use them directly because they're strings.

If I create different tables, let's say for UInt8:
`CREATE TABLE UInt8Table(key UInt32, name String, value UInt8) ENGINE=MergeTree ORDER BY key`

I would like to retrieve all informations when searching for the name or even for the key. But the problem is that I have a lot of tables for all types. So if I search for let's say "A" I want to have its value but in the right type.

Does somebody succeeded to resolve this problem or is there a solution ?

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and perhaps share some of your code. It is pretty clear what you are doing to avoid the problem but not entirely clear what is the problem that you are trying to solve.